# Как сделать подбирание предметов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно, чтобы когда персонаж в 3Д игре подходил к предмету и жал Ф, предмет перемещался в руки игроку и передвигался с ним, как в игре Beneath the Cardboard
А потом на Е выбрасывал
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

создай триггер в необходимой области.

Если обьект с тэгом "Item" попадает в триггер и нажимается кнопка F - перемещай обьект внутрь руки в инспекторе. При условии что в руке ничего нет.

И на Е выкидывай предмет в инспекторе из руки во внешний мир.